# How to get number of all rows in livewire render paginated method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In my laravel 7 app using livewire/livewire 1.3  I use pagination
in component :

```
class Facilities extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        ...
        return view('livewire.admin.facilities.container', [
            'facilityDataRows' => Facility
                ::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->paginate($backend_pagination_by_rows)
        ]);
    }
```

I also need to get number of all rows in related table, how can I do it with method above ?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, but maybe [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods)

```
{{ $facilityDataRows->total() }}
```

Comment: Just don't add link. Give a brief about the solution and then add a reference.

Comment: I just forget, that in "return view(" method of render any other parameters can be set too.